# Display a loading icon until the page loads completely

Tags: jquery, loader

I want to show a loader until data processed and page loads completely.

HTML:-

```
       <div class="loader" id="dvProgressBar" runat="server" visible="false">
            <div class="center">
                <img alt="" src="../Images/ajax_loader.gif" width="100" height="100" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Where should I show this div?

Is there any way to make it automatic (on every valid click)

Comment: You mean during `ajax` calls?

Comment: on any valid click it may be ajax call or any postback

Comment: For `postback`, You can just show it directly on `click`. But for `ajax` you have particular method called `$(document).ajaxStart` and `$(document).ajaxComplete` where you can `show/hide` your loader respectively..

Comment: any chance of getting the exact code for $(document).ajaxStart and $(document).ajaxComplete?